# pipe charecters data in expression engine query as parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, expressionengine

```
$query =  $this->EE->db->query("SELECT * FROM exp_categories WHERE parent_id=$parent_id order by cat_id ASC");

and $parent id = 4|7|5|6 (for category parent id passed from template by user)
```

now query should return result for both parent id's.

it's showing result only for the last parent id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not totally clear on what you are asking.  I think you want your query to be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM exp_categories 
WHERE parent_id 
IN (4, 5, 6, 7) 
ORDER BY cat_id ASC;
```

If so you need to take $parent_id from piped-list (4|7|5|6) and transform it to a comma-separated list (4, 5, 6, 7).